# jQuery copy and paste using document.execCommand("copy") and ("paste")

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one dropdown upon selection of which I want to copy the value of that dropdown and paste in an input field below without using clt+v every time

Here is the code what I tried:

```
$('body').append(`<div id="selectDialog" title="Select Regex Type" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
          <select id="listSelection">
            <option value ="">None</option>
            <option value ="[a-z]+">Single Digit Integers</option>
            <option value ="^[0-9]">Multi Digit Number</option>
            <option value ="/^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/">Decimal Number</option>
          </select>

          <div style="margin:10px">
                 <button id="closeSelection" style="background- 
                                 color:#3B5E9E" >save</button>
          </div>

 </div>`);



$(function () {

            $("#selectDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
            });


            $('#changePattern').on("click", function () {
                $("#selectDialog").dialog("open");
            });


            $("#listSelection")
                .change(function () {

                    var s = $("#listSelection option:selected").val();
                    $("#changePattern").val(s);
                    $("#changePattern").attr("patternMask" , s);
                    $('#changePattern').select();
                     document.execCommand("copy");
                     $('#reg').select();

                })
                .trigger("change");

         $('#reg').select( function (){

         /*here I am trying to copy using document.texecCommand("copy");
but unable to copy*/
         });


            $('#closeSelection').on("click", function () {
                $("#selectDialog").dialog("close");
            });

    });

});
```

on clicking input having an id changePattern , i am opening an dropdown from which i am populating another field with id =reg

h i am saving a pattern to:

```
<input id="changePattern" />
<input id="reg" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `<input type="hidden">` or `<input hidden>`

`.on()` change of `select` store it's selected value to a hidden `input`. then register the `input`s to the click event. Whenever a click happens on those `input`s the value of the hidden `input` will be pasted to it.

Did you get an `.execCommand()` to work on an `input`? `document.execCommand()` are for `contenteditable` elements not `form` elements.

---

### Demo

```js
$('select').on('change', function(event) {

  $('#X').val($(this).val());

});

$('input').on('click', function(event) {

  if ($('#X').val() !== null) {

    $(this).val($('#X').val());

  }
});
```

```html
<input id='X' hidden value=null>
<select>
  <option value=''></option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input>
<input>
<input>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```